# Can a symmetric matrix be found using matrix-vector operation while maintaining matrix-vector operatin?

Tags: matrix

Consider $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ its not a special matrix and in the worst case all of its entries are non-zero. I am looking for a way to compute $AA^{T}$ using matrix-vector operation. The total number of flops are $(2n-1)\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ because all I have to do for a symmetric matrix like $C=AA^{T}$ is to compute the diagonal entires which are $C(i,i)=A(i,:)^TA(i,:)$. What I want now is to compute the lower triangular part and then when I am done I just say that the upper triangular part is the same as the lower triangular part. The problem is can I do it in matrix-vector multiplication or will it force me to perform unnecessary multiplication (like multiplying elements in the upper part)? It is clear that a vector-vector computation would work but I am interested to know if a matrix-vector computation would work or not.

Comment: It's not clear to me .. do you need all of $\mathbf C = \mathbf A \mathbf A^T$, or just the diagonal entries? Do you need to tabulate $\mathbf C$, or just apply it's action to a vector? Your question is close but not quite there.

Comment: I wish to compute $C=AA^{T}$ by just computing the lower triangular part of $C$ that is where I am stuck I can do that using scalar operation but I was wondering if its possible to do it as a matrix-vector operation @rchilton1980

Comment: The diagonal entries and the upper triangular part will follow from the symmetry of $C$ @rchilton1980

Comment: Which language are you using? I think that in Matlab and Python a call of the form `A * A'` (with the same *variable* on both sides) already gets translated to a `?SYRK` BLAS call that does this under the hood. (More generally, if the question is "what is the fastest way to do this?", then I believe the answer will be "use `?SYRK`".

Comment: Indeed I am using MATLAB. No the question is not the fastest, I am asking if a matrix-vector operation can be implemented in the lower triangular part of $AA^{T}$ or only scalar operation can be performed. I am not using any MATLAB's built in function as I am writing my own algorithm @FedericoPoloni

Comment: I think that in order not to compute entries that have already been computed you would need to be able to compute matrix-vector products with matrices of the form A(1:i, :), for all i. Would that be acceptable?

Comment: Indeed, are they of the form $A(i+1:n,:)*A(:,i)$? @AmitHochman

Comment: Right, well, almost. I think the vector would be A(i,:)’. That would give you all the elements except the diagonal ones.

Comment: Can you do matrix-vector products only with $A$ or also with $A^T$? Or alternatively, can you do products with vectors *from the left*, i.e., $v^TA$?